# Create object with random key jquery

Tags: jquery, json, object

I want to create a object with a specific name and an array, (e.g. myObject = { name : array()}). I have this code :

```
 $(".selectedQueues").each(function(){
            var selectionName = $(this).find("input").val();
            var containedQueues = new Array();
            $(this).find("li").each(function(){
                containedQueues.push($(this).text());
            });
            var object = new Object();
            object.selectionName = containedQueues;
            console.log(object);
        });
```

And when I print the object it is like {selectionName : array[]} , but I want it to be {the value in selectionName : array[]}, can someone help me?

Comment: Remember, objects can be accessed with `[]` as well as `.`.  `object[selectionName] = containedQueues;`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `object.selectionName` to `object[selectionName]`:

```
$(".selectedQueues").each(function(){
    var selectionName = $(this).find("input").val();
    var containedQueues = new Array();
    $(this).find("li").each(function(){
        containedQueues.push($(this).text());
    });
    var object = new Object();
    object[selectionName] = containedQueues;
    console.log(object);
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bMK2w/1/)

**EDIT:** I was unsure if you were looking to just use `selectionName`, or the actual name property, which you need to change that portion to:

```
var selectionName = $(this).find("input").attr('name');
```